# For what to use PlayFab Player Data (Title), and Player Data (Publisher)?

Tags: playfab

I started using PlayFab. Could someone help me and explain with small example for what to use Player Data (Title), and Player Data (Publisher), and for what not to use?

Comment: [Searching the PlayFab documentation for those terms brings up tutorials & quickstart info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=player%20data%20title&scope=PlayFab). If that info isn't helping to resolve your problem, you probably need more info in your question explaining what you've tried & what specific issues you encountered.

Comment: I see both are the same. So, what are they specific for? At less give me an example. Unfortunately, their forum is bad.

Comment: [from the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/): Player Publisher data is data associated with the player account, as opposed to the player account plus the title. It is used to save information about a player relevant to all titles in your studio (which may also contain title-specific information, for purposes of cross-title rewards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it might be good to clarify the [difference between player data & player publisher data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/#player-data-vs-player-publisher-data):

> **Player data** is player information that is specific to a game title. It should be used for title-specific information - such as saving your player's position in a dungeon, or other game-specific data.
>
> **Player *Publisher* data** is data associated with the player account, as opposed to the player account plus the title. It is used to save information about a player relevant to all titles in your studio (which may also contain title-specific information, for purposes of cross-title rewards).

And as noted later on:

> They are both dictionaries mapping a string to a JSON blob (or other arbitrary string value).

Based on your question usage, it *seems* like you are asking about **player data** called `title` & `publisher`. Based on the documentation, that means for some game XYZ, you would use those mappings to store the title for XYZ and the publisher for XYZ. Sometimes these are referred to in the documentation as Key/Value Pairs or KVPs.

The definition for player data says it hold game title specific information such as the player's position. But there could be more than one game that uses player position. As mentioned [here in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/player-details#player-toolbar-overview), the title establishes the current scope, which is to say makes sure that you are referring to the data for the intended game.

That same documentation also explains that the publisher field is used for managing account data across several titles. For example, if a publisher has multiple games, they might want to encourage players of one title to purchase & play your other titles. In that case you could [grant a reward for playing multiple titles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/using-player-publisher-data). By consistently using the publisher KVP, you can more easily query for the necessary information to see if a reward should be given. The documentation also gives a link to an [example project using simple in-game cross promotion](https://github.com/PlayFab/PlayFab-Samples/tree/master/Recipes/SimpleCrossPromotion) where players get rewarded for participating in more than one of your games.